# Package GraphFrames Spark2.0

Tags: apache-spark-2.0, scala-2.11, graphframes

I have spark 2.0 Scala 2.11.8 and I am trying to include graph frames package.
    I typed the following in the scala shell:

```
<spark-shell --packages graphframes:graphframes:0.1.0-spark1.6>

But still I got the error message:

scala> import org.graphframes._
<console>:23: error: object graph frames is not a member of package org
       import org.graphframes._
                  ^

scala> import org.graphframes.GrahFrame
<console>:23: error: object graphframes is not a member of package org
       import org.graphframes.GrahFrame
```

Please refer to the screenshot attached.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

`$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --packages graphframes:graphframes:0.5.0-spark2.1-s_2.11`